# XAMPP: не открывается localhost/phpmyadmin/

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
Ошибка: Не удается получить доступ к сайту.

При этом php работает, запускается так: mySite:8080

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл решение. Открывается так: http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/